# Is this the correct way to use MySQL @variables in PHP?

Tags: mysql, mysql-workbench

I was given a MySQL query:

```
SET @COD_PAIS = 3, @ID_CARTERA = 8; 
SELECT 
    C.DES_PERMADURACION AS Item
    , B.POR_MADURACION AS Percentage_Distribution 
FROM dficha_mes A 
JOIN det_maduraciones B 
    ON ( A.ID_FICHA_MES = B.ID_FICHA_MES ) 
JOIN mpermaduraciones C 
    ON ( B.ID_PERMADURACION = C.ID_PERMADURACION ) 
WHERE A.ID_CARTERA = @ID_CARTERA 
AND A.COD_PAIS = @COD_PAIS 
AND B.F_CORTE = ( 
                    SELECT 
                        F_ULT_CIERRE_MENSUAL 
                    FROM mpaises 
                    WHERE COD_PAIS = @COD_PAIS );
```

The table has rows and columns in Spanish.

When I run this query using PHP's `mysql_query()`, I get the following error:

```
You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'SELECT 
        C.DES_PERMADURACION AS Item
        , B.POR_MADURACION AS Percentage_Distrib' at line 2
```

However this query runs perfectly from MySQL Workbench or even SQLYog.

Any pointers here?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can't submit multiple queries in a single string in PHP. You'll need to do them as separate calls to `mysql_query()`, or use the mysqli interface instead (which is what you should be doing anyway).

http://php.net/manual/en/book.mysqli.php

Answer (score 1):

I believe `mysql_query()` can only execute 1 query at a time.

Answer (score 1):

First of all, please forget about mysql_* commands because they are deprecated.

Second, as it was stated you can not use more than one query at a time.

Third, take a look here :
[MySql variables and php](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1580700/mysql-variables-and-php)

and here:
http://www.webhostingtalk.com/showthread.php?t=360276

Comment: Thanks a lot for reminding me about this again. I'll move the codebase to PDO; its just that the legacy code had the above issue. I'll migrate soon. Thanks.